# Alarm and baseAdapter [android Application]

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, alarm

I've a `listView` in `Activity(A)`, which contains two buttons. One of them should be disabled when the row is created, and when the alarm goes off it should be enabled.

I make a code to do this but when the alarm goes off it enables the button and moves me to the `activity (A)`, and as you know if I move to `Activity (A)` the `getView()` function will be called so the same button will be disabled again !!!

How can I make it enabled even if the alarm moves me to `Activity (A)` ...

Note: my adapter extends: `baseAdapter`

any suggestion 
thanks in advance

Monerah ...

Comment: @superM thanks for ur note, but I'm not lier if anyone helped me I'll accept it if not i won't accept so if any person have same my question can take right solution.. 
 about my code it's so huge, when I put it in other question one of the member said we couldn't check  huge code ... 

thanks again for ur responses

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter contains some data. You should have there attribute for every row indicating if button should be enabled. E.g. boolean isButtonEnabled = false. When alarm goes of set isButtonEnabled = true; In getView check if button is enabled or not and according to it enable or disable button

Comment: actually when the row is created I make the button disable and when the alarm goes of I'm make it enable buuuut when the alarm goes of it moves me to the same activity of the list so the button goes disable ..
My desired senaroi is: to make the button disable when it created in the first time then make it enable when the alarm goes of then when the user press it must be disable again and so on